# How to send password to server using vue or javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I have created vue components for login and registration. How do I send password to the server?? Should I just encrypt the password using `bcrypt` on the client side and then send it to Laravel or should I just send the plain password to Laravel and use `bcrypt($request->get('password'));` What would be a good option?

If I should encrypt the password in the vue component, what package/function should I use so that it will encrypt the password in the same way as Laravel/PHP does??

Comment: 1. You *hash* passwords, you don't encrypt them. 2. There is little security benefit to sending the hash instead of the password, as a MitM attack still gets what they need to log in. 3. Use https to secure the password in transit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not really need to encrypt the password in your javascript code. It is more important to serve your PHP on a HTTPS server.

The data sending between browser and your web server will be encrypted by the SSL/TLS cert.

Here are some guides to setup a HTTPS enabled web server, I assume your php is hosted on NGINX or Apache with php-fpm or apache php modules.

With [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), it provides a free SSL/TLS cert for your web server to secure the communication between client browser and itself.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: so can I just send my password as it is using axios after having SSL??

Comment: Right, be sure that you have forward/redirect the normal HTTP on port 80 to HTTPS port 443 on your web server, such that user will not accidentally use the HTTP (insecure) to send login info

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to encrypt password on client side!

- Leaving user's password unencrypted means that it will be vulnerable to MITM attacks
- SSL termination very often happens on load balancers, which means plaintext password travels from that point to your web server unprotected, where logging can be enabled by sysadmins, etc.
- developers or sysadmins should NOT have possibility to get to user's passwords, which will happen if you will not encrypt password on client

Comment: can you explain this further?  I do not understand, for instance, why a password is susceptible to MITM attacks if the server uses HTTPS and only the HTTPS protocol is enabled (HTTP-only is disallowed)?  You can argue that HTTPS is not *particularly* strong encryption, but I feel like that is another argument. *Assuming* HTTPS is sufficiently strong, how does the Man In The Middle attack occur?  I genuinely do not understand.